# nav menu not fitting on mobile browsers

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, mobile

I am having a slight issue getting my navigation menu to fit on a mobile device - iphone/ipad. [click here](http://iamnatesmithen.com/bodyworks/header.php)
I have set my css properties to the following:

```
    #wrapper{
    max-width: 1600px;
    min-width: 320px;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    position: relative;
}
#header{
    max-width: 1018px;
    min-width: 320px;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
} 

#social-tabs{
    display: block;
    padding: 4px;
    margin: 5px 0px;
}

#nav-menu{
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 1018px;
    min-width: 320px;
}
```

I have also apply a screen resizer to my site, however i'm still not having any joy..

```
 function reSize($target){
 $target.css('width', $(window).width()+'px');
}
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(window).bind('resize', reSize($('#header')));
    $(window).trigger('resize');
});
```

Is there anyone out there that can pick up where i am going wrong?

Comment: Remove the javascript solution and use css media queries.

Comment: Argh! I was trying to look for a short cut

Comment: If you have any specific problem with media query/css you can ask, i'll be happy to help.

Comment: I'm fine using media query, i'm slightly confused as to how i will resize my navigation onto a mobile device as been as i'm not using <img> tags

Comment: I dont understand you exactly, an image of how you want this to look in mobile might be helpful. If your concern is with background image instead of img, you can use background size http://www.css3.info/preview/background-size/ .Also accept the wonderful answer by @Pointy

Answer (score 1):

When you try to bind the resize handler, you're doing it wrong:

```
$(window).bind('resize', resize.bind(window, $('#header')));
```

would improve things. Your code as written *called* the "resize" function. What you need to do is to pass a reference to a function. Another (perhaps simpler) equivalent would be:

```
$(window).bind('resize', function() { resize( $('#header') ); });
```

Now with that said, you're still going to have problems. Handling "resize" events is not going to help you on a mobile device because there's no resizing going on anyway.  What you really need to do is investigate [CSS Media Queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/Media_queries), and base your solution in CSS and not JavaScript.

(It's also important to note that "resize" events fire quite quickly on desktop browsers as the browser window is interactively resized. Obviously, turning a phone or tablet on its side should fire just one event, but on a desktop/laptop computer, the browser fires a zillion "resize" events while the window corner widget is dragged, so JavaScript handlers that update the DOM tend to get bogged down pretty seriously.)